# When using 'rsync' to duplicate a partition, the sizes come out different. Should I worry?

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, lts

I have been using `rsync` on the Parted Magic CD to duplicate my Ubuntu 14.04LTS partition to a USB drive as a backup.  Once completed, the size on the destination USB drive is larger (>2.1GB) than the sourced SSHD drive.   Should I be concerned and why?

```
root@PartedMagic:~# df  
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sdb1      122940824 97847408  18825340  84% /media/sdb1  
/dev/sda3      239541408 95747516 131602840  43% /media/sda3
```

Here is the script I am currently using within the ROXTerm AP:

```
mount /dev/sdb1
mount /dev/sda3
cd /media/sda3
rsync -avpHAX --del --numeric-ids . /media/sdb1/
```

Here is the `fdisk -l` information:

```
root@PartedMagic:/media/sda3# fdisk -l  
Disk /dev/ram0: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram1: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram2: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram3: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram4: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram5: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram6: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram7: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram8: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram9: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram10: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram11: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram12: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram13: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram14: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk /dev/ram15: 16 MiB, 16777216 bytes, 32768 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes   
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disklabel type: dos  
Disk identifier: 0x5bc53d8b  
Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type  
/dev/sda1  *            63  955604991 955604929 455.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT  
/dev/sda2        955604992  976766975  21161984  10.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT  
/dev/sda3        976766976 1463753951 486986976 232.2G 83 Linux  
/dev/sda4       1463754750 1953523711 489768962 233.6G  5 Extended  
/dev/sda5       1463754752 1572020223 108265472  51.6G 83 Linux  
/dev/sda6       1572022272 1936746495 364724224 173.9G 83 Linux   
/dev/sda7       1936748544 1953523711  16775168     8G 82 Linux swap  
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.  
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.  
Disk /dev/sdb: 119.2 GiB, 128035323904 bytes, 250068992 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disklabel type: dos  
Disk identifier: 0xd25c4889  
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type  
/dev/sdb1  *       63 250067789 250067727 119.2G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Note: -A, --acls                  preserve ACLs (implies -p) so `-avHAX` should provide the same result as `-avpHAX`

Comment: Compare which folders are differing in size: `diff <(cd /media/sdb1; du -hxd1 .) <(cd /media/sda3; du -hxd1 .)`. That might provide a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: Note that you are syncing directories, not partitions. Partition  duplication  can be done with `dd` and `dc3dd`

Comment: Thanks for the 'diff' command.  The results showed no differences which reassured me the 'rsync' is working correctly.
root@PartedMagic:~# mount /dev/sdb1    
root@PartedMagic:~# mount /dev/sda3     
root@PartedMagic:~# diff <(cd /media/sdb1; du -hxd1 .) <(cd /media/sda3; du -hxd1 .)    
root@PartedMagic:~# df    
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on    
/dev/sdb1      122940824 97847408  18825340  84% /media/sdb1    
/dev/sda3      239541408 95747516 131602840  43% /media/sda3    
root@PartedMagic:~#

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to worry about. The reason it does this is due to a few things. The first one is the system information in the partition table. When you copy a partition, you only copy the user files into a new one, and all the temp files in the old one are left alone. Another factor is the long standing issue of base 10 memory units. This is also recognisable in USB sticks and HDD's (ever noticed how they have less memory than what is says on the packet? This is due to memory calculations in base 10). And another issue could just be a user error. If you've not got rights on a directory, or if something else stops you from copying it, the files just won't mirror onto the new partition.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The 1000 vs 1024 explains the 2+% difference.

Comment: @MarkLKeppinger That's what I thought. Damn memory units, makes it so hard to prove a Gb is actually 1024 Mb :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses.  They have helped me narrow down where and why I was having issues.  One fact that I recently discover that impacted this problem was the source partition was an extended partition while the destination partition was a primary partition.  Once I changed the destination partition to an extended partition, the numbers are almost identical. So the 1000 vs 1024 is related to primary vs extended partitions. I suspect the now few xK differences has to do with bad sectors (the `diff` -gospel truth- still shows no difference).

Here is a `df` with the USB drive connected and one without the USB drive (/dev/sdb5) connected, when booted from the SSD drive (`/dev/sda6`).  Only a 8K difference.  Please note the partition name of the `/` directory in the two `df`s.  IMO, a visual bug that should be reported to the Ubuntu people:

```
:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1008240        8   1008232   1% /dev
tmpfs             203808     1200    202608   1% /run
/dev/sdb5       32896880 12291920  18910868  40% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1019020    16400   1002620   2% /run/shm
none              102400       40    102360   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1       16382888  3650412  11877240  24% /media/markk/Ubuntu 15.10
/dev/sdb2        1125376    26325   1099051   3% /media/markk/Boot
/dev/sda1         323580    58804    264776  19% /media/markk/SYSTEM
/dev/sda2       91773948 62945400  28828548  69% /media/markk/D345EB1A3E8C47E1
/dev/sda7       72539432  3274148  65557380   5% /media/markk/519c4876-b4b6-43e5-8876-1656394e69a9

:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1008240        8   1008232   1% /dev
tmpfs             203808     1180    202628   1% /run
/dev/sda6       32896880 12291912  18910876  40% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1019020    16368   1002652   2% /run/shm
none              102400       40    102360   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1         323580    58804    264776  19% /media/markk/SYSTEM
/dev/sda2       91773948 62945400  28828548  69% /media/markk/D345EB1A3E8C47E1
/dev/sda7       72539432  3274148  65557380   5% /media/markk/519c4876-b4b6-43e5-8876-1656394e69a9
```

An additional note to those looking to perform backups to a boot'able USB drive… My initial `rsync` command with the `-avpHAX` worked fine with the first attempt to populate the USB drive.  Subsequent attempts to send "incremental changes" does not complete when it starts to reference the "Parted Magic" CD.  Not sure why, but I suspect it is following a hard link to some `/...` directory.  The example I was following had a `-avp` option and I added the `HAX` part in an attempt to resolve the "Used" K count issue.

The only issue I have left to resolve is related to the 'grub' process is complaining about not finding a certain devices ID.  Things boot fine when I acknowledge it to ignore the issue.